# Best way to dynamically fire API queries using payloads from a JSON Array?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, web-api-testing

I need to measure the response times of an API query to different combinations of payloads.

While exploring multiple API testing tools I came across Jmeter. Which provides a CSV Data Set configuration.

[image: Jmeter Configuration Screenshot]

But what I need is selecting a random name of columns from a csv and put those is a query.

```
{
  "query": ["rcol1":val1, "rcol2":val2 ... ]
}
```

Is this achievable ?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your request payload dynamically using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).

See [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) class documentation and [Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html#_builders) article for more details.

If you want a code snippet you will need to provide:

1. First 2-3 lines of your CSV file
2. The desired payload format showing how data from CSV should be organized

Comment: Here's the required data from points 1 & 2. https://pastes.io/mz8dyhsfis